# How do I write a method in java that reads a text file and finds the number of occurrences of each character?

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist, character

How do I write a method in java that reads a text file and finds the number of occurrences of each character? Then after it stores the items into an arraylist as you read them.

Comment: What have you tried? We won't write the entire thing for you, but if you can show us what you have tried and where you are having problems, we will happily assist you.

Answer (score 0):

First open the .txt file and read its contents 
then create a Hashmap and iterate over the characters for counting

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    HashMap<Character,Integer> hm;    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
         //iterate over the string and increment  
         //hashmap.get("character") by one
         line = br.readLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the File with a `FileReader` and then use an `int[]` that stores the occurences of each character.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
int[] characters = new int[65535];
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;

while ((i = br.read()) >= 0)
{
     characters[i]++;
}
```